# How can I check for the presence of an attribute in XML/JSON using RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, json, rspec

I'm looking for the right way to check for the **presence** of an attribute in a XML or JSON response. I don't care if the value is nil, empty or any other value, in fact, my response could contain 3 states for this specific attribute:

- Not present at all
- Present but value is `nil`
- Present and value is a `datetime`

So I need some way to unify and simplify all these states (because all are valid in this specific test) and to just ask if the attribute (**last_visit_at**) is present.
The same I can do to test if it's nil, or not, i.e with JSON:

```
JSON.parse(response.body).first["last_visit_at"].should_not be_nil
JSON.parse(response.body).first["last_visit_at"].should be_nil
```

This doesn't work when the value is nil, obviously (nil does not respond to either #exist? or #exists?):

```
JSON.parse(response.body).first["last_visit_at"].should exist
```

Is there any way to do this, and could it be valid for both, JSON and XML responses? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
JSON.parse(response.body).first.keys.include?("last_visit_at").should be_true
```

Comment: or just `...keys.should include('last_visit_at')`.